# Laravel - save many related models in saved event not work on update

Tags: php, laravel, foreign-keys

I have three models to manage roles in my application: `Role`, `User`, `UserRole`.

In `User` model class there is an `HasMany` **relation** and in the database there is a **foreign key** in `UserRole` related table on `user_code` field:

```
public function userRoles(): HasMany
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\UserRole', 'user_code', 'code');
}
```

I have a method for assign roles **after saving** an `User` model:

```
public function assignRole(...$roles)
{
    $userRoles = collect($roles)->flatten()->map(function($role) {
        return new UserRole(['code' => $role instanceof Role ? $role->code: $role]);
    });

    $this::saved(
        function ($object) use ($userRoles) {
            $object->userRoles()->delete();
            $object->userRoles()->saveMany($userRoles);
            $object->load('userRoles');
        }
    );

    return $this;
}
```

In `UserController` there is an **update action** for change roles to an `User`:

```
public function update(UpdateUser $request, User $user)
{
    $data = $request->all(); 
    $user->fill($data);
    $user->assignRole($data['roles']);

    if (!$user->save()) {
    ...
```

The problem is that when I update the `$user` I get an **exception**:

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException
>
> > SQLSTATE[23503]: Foreign key violation...

This is caused by `$object->userRoles()->saveMany($userRoles);` in saved event.

I think it's due to the fact when it saves the related models the updated `$user` is **not persisted** to the database and the foreign key constraints on `user_code` are **violated**. But the saved event callback ** works well on create** user model. Why? And how can I resolve it?

Comment: Have you tested with just the `$object->userRoles()->delete();` line to see if the delete works? Also, does the error message show any more (possibly useful) information?

Comment: delete() relations works, the error message is the standard of SQLSTATE for foreign key violation.

Comment: @alvarofvr post your migrations please.

Comment: It must be the roles input that is wrong can you dd() $roles in the beginning of assignRole function

Comment: I have not used migrations so far.

Comment: @mrhn $roles = ['1'];

Comment: Then there is clearly no users with that code, can you show how the foreign key is made?

Comment: Look at first part of code in the answer.

Comment: That is not how it is made, thou if what you are saying is correct, you do not have an user with code 1 in your database otherwise the foreign key wont fail. And include the full foreign key violation, i usually includes the excact fields

Answer (score 0):

That part with `$this::saved(` makes no sense to me. What are you trying to achieve?  You might need a Model Observer : https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#observers

Your `$this::saved()` calls `saveMany()`, which in return triggers the `$this::saved()` event "many" times, which then calls `saveMany()` again, and again. You seem to be in an infinite loop which ends as soon as you hit that foreign key constraint.

Comment: Hi @13h50, $this::saved is just an event and I want to trigger the saving of UserRoles models when the User model is saved. It's clear and there is no loop XD

Answer (score 0):

Cut out the manual triggering of your role updates and just use an observer to handle it.

In `App\Providers\AppServiceProvider.php : boot()`:

```php
\App\Models\User::saved(function ($user) {
    $userRoles = collect($roles)->flatten()->map(function($role) {
        return new UserRole(['code' => $role instanceof Role ? $role->code: $role]);
    });

    $user->userRoles()->delete();
    $user->userRoles()->saveMany($userRoles);
    $user->load('userRoles');
});
```